# No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp() in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the `web (Chrome)` to run my application. But, I get an error. Here is the error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following FirebaseException was thrown building App(dirty, dependencies:
[UncontrolledProviderScope], state: _AppState#4cc6e):
[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  App App:file:///Users/name/development/projects/flutter/hello_world/lib/src/hello_world.dart:46:21

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#1      <anonymous closure> (http://localhost:7357/packages/riverpod/src/stack_trace.dart:7:11)
#2      <anonymous closure> (http://localhost:7357/packages/riverpod/src/framework/provider_base.dart:332:25)
#3      map (http://localhost:7357/packages/riverpod/src/framework/provider_base.dart:1158:17)
#4      get requireState (http://localhost:7357/packages/riverpod/src/framework/provider_base.dart:331:17)
#5      readSelf (http://localhost:7357/packages/riverpod/src/framework/provider_base.dart:826:12)
#6      read (http://localhost:7357/packages/riverpod/src/framework/provider_base.dart:174:29)
#7      watch (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter_riverpod/src/consumer.dart:505:20)
#8      build (http://localhost:7357/packages/bizzee/src/app.dart:59:26)
#9      build (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4919:27)
#10     build (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter_riverpod/src/consumer.dart:485:20)
#11     performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4806:15)
#12     performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#13     rebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#14     [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#15     [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4968:11)
#16     mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
#17     inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#18     updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#19     mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6215:14)
#20     inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#21     updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#22     performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#23     rebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#24     [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#25     mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
#26     inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#27     updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#28     mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6215:14)
#29     inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#30     updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#31     mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6215:14)
#32     inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#33     updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#34     performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#35     performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#36     rebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#37     [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#38     [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4968:11)
#39     mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
#40     inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#41     inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6350:36)
#42     mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6362:32)
#43     inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#44     updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#45     performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#46     performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#47     rebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#48     [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#49     [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4968:11)
#50     mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
#51     inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#52     updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#53     mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6215:14)
#54     inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#55     updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#56     performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#57     performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#58     rebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#59     [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#60     [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4968:11)
#61     mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
#62     inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#63     updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#64     mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6215:14)
#65     inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#66     updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#67     performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#68     performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#69     rebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#70     [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#71     [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4968:11)
#72     mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
#73     inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#74     updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#75     mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6215:14)
#76     inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#77     updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#78     performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#79     performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#80     rebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#81     [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#82     [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4968:11)
#83     mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
#84     inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#85     updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#86     performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#87     rebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#88     [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#89     mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
#90     inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#91     updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#92     performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#93     performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#94     rebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#95     [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#96     [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4968:11)
#97     mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
#98     inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#99     updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#100    mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6215:14)
#101    inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#102    updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#103    mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6215:14)
#104    inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#105    updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#106    performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#107    rebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#108    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#109    mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
#110    inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#111    updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#112    mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6215:14)
#113    inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#114    updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#115    performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#116    performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#117    rebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#118    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#119    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4968:11)
#120    mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
#121    inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#122    updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#123    performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#124    rebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#125    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#126    mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
#127    inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#128    updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#129    performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#130    rebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#131    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#132    mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
#133    inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#134    updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#135    performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#136    performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#137    rebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#138    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#139    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4968:11)
#140    mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
#141    inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#142    updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#143    performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#144    rebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#145    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#146    mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
#147    inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#148    updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#149    performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#150    rebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#151    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#152    mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
#153    inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#154    updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#155    mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6215:14)
#156    inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#157    updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#158    performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#159    rebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#160    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#161    mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
#162    inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#163    updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#164    performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#165    rebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#166    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#167    mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
#168    inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#169    updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#170    performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#171    performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#172    rebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#173    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#174    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4968:11)
#175    mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
#176    inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#177    updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#178    performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#179    performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#180    rebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#181    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#182    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4968:11)
#183    mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
#184    inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#185    updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#186    performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#187    performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#188    rebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#189    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#190    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4968:11)
#191    mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
#192    inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#193    updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#194    mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6215:14)
#195    inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#196    updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#197    performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#198    rebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#199    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#200    mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
#201    inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#202    updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#203    performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#204    performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#205    rebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#206    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#207    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4968:11)
#208    mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
#209    inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#210    updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#211    performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#212    performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#213    rebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#214    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#215    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4968:11)
#216    mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
#217    inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#218    inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6350:36)
#219    mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6362:32)
#220    inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#221    updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#222    performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#223    performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#224    rebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#225    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#226    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4968:11)
#227    mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
#228    inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#229    updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#230    performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#231    rebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#232    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#233    mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
#234    inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#235    updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#236    performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#237    rebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#238    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#239    mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
#240    inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#241    updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#242    mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6215:14)
#243    inflateWidget (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:15)
#244    updateChild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#245    performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#246    performRebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#247    rebuild (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#248    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#249    [_firstBuild] (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4968:11)
#250    mount (http://localhost:7357/packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
...... (too long)
```

I initialized `Firebase` in the `main()` method after `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` like this:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  await runZonedGuarded(
    () async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      GoRouter.setUrlPathStrategy(UrlPathStrategy.path);
      runApp(const ProviderScope(child: HelloWorld()));
      ......
    },
    (Object error, StackTrace stack) {
        debugPrint(error.toString());
        debugPrint(stack.toString());
    },
  );
}
```

I never get this error when I run my app with `Android Emulator`.

How can I fix this error? Appreciate if someone can advise. Thank you in advance!

Comment: could you share your code where you initialize firebase app

Comment: @Md.KamrulAmin, I shared my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the latest version of Firebase. Please follow the web installation steps carefully. I am using Firebase too in my web app and I faced the same issue in the beginning. After installation remember to run your project again from the beginning.

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=web

Comment: I am not using the latest version of `Firebase`.

Comment: I am using version 11.2.1 and the latest version is 11.8.0.

Comment: No worries it will still work. Just start the installation from start and follow the steps. It will work. In step 4, only add the firebase plugins you need and remember to call firebase configure in your terminal window

Comment: I get the error `zsh: command not found: flutterfire`.

Comment: After running the command "dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli" did you get a warning message? You just need to add the path to your path variables. Go to 'Finder' in your Mac. On top select 'Go->Home'. When inside 'Home', show hidden files using keyboard shortcut (Command + Shift + . (period)). Then, look for a file .zshrc. Add the path in the zshrc file that you get in the warning message, it should look something like this: export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"

Comment: I get the error `/Users/name/.pub-cache/bin/flutterfire: line 8: dart: command not found`.

Comment: it is still not finding flutterfire in your path. Show me your .zshrc file. You can try restarting your system too

Comment: It's 55 characters too long.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248150/discussion-between-md-kamrul-amin-and-my-car).